# How to access webtable data in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, coding-style

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK6Xg.png)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]

I tried to automate the web table code by using valid Xpath, stream, and lambda expressions. But getting asserts error, I don't understand how to resolve this, If anyone knows how to resolve it, please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Included sources [should be in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5043481), not an image. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

originalList and sortedList is not equal therefore it stopped in Assert.asserTrue line. this code expected a true condition.
Maybe you can check the orginaList and sortedList.